# Installing dependency from eclipse.org through Maven

Tags: java, maven

I am new to maven and only have a pretty basic understanding.
The goal is to develop a Java Application, which itself uses libraries from

```
https://git.eclipse.org/r/plugins/gitiles/app4mc/org.eclipse.app4mc/+/refs/heads/master
```

It itself has a pom.xml and by this seems to be a maven project, but is not content of the maven repositories I have searched. How do I have to add this to my `pom.xml`, so it will be downloaded and compiled within my project, to be used in and packed to the final generated jar?

Comment: You need to clone the repo and build the packages yourself, then tell maven to use your local repo to resolve the dependency.

Comment: Is there no possibility to automate this? The goal is for future installments to not have to do this by hand

Comment: The repo simply isn't available as a ready-to-use artifact. Maven deals with artifacts. you have to somehow build that artifact in order to include it. Sure, you can automate that, but you really only need to create the artifact *once*.

Comment: Ok sorry, I do not know if my understanding here is good enough. So, if I manually download and build the git with maven, then append it as a dependency, maven will from this now the next time, how to download and build this?

Comment: No, not at all. As I said, you need to clone the repo, build the artifact, install it in your *local* maven repo, then tell maven to resolve the dependency from your local repo. You realize maven has a local repo for artifacts, right?

Comment: I understood this fact of the local repository. And I think I got your procedure. My question is, if I want to write an installer for my project, that different people use on different pcs, I want to have it automated so they do not have to manually clone and download, and I do not have to include the jar into my git. That is why I am searching for some kind of automation here.

Comment: Maven isn't meant to be deployed as an installer. You build your program as a single jar and deploy the ready-to-use program. Installers that fetch parts of your program are a different kind of beast, but solutions for that also exist. But fetching source code and building the software on the client system is nothing any installer I have ever seen has done. The client likely doesn't even have the build tools.